# Get current position of clicked ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have default layout animation implemented from this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Then on each row I have textView and edit textView. When textView is selected I am showing timePicker and showing button. When the time picked and button clicked I need to update appropriate textview.

The problem is that I can't get the position of the clicked row.

Here is the java code for adding row and picking the time:

```
private void addMealItem() {
        // Instantiate a new "row" view.
        final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_meal_builder_listview_item, mContainerView, false);


        // Set a click listener for the "X" button in the row that will remove the row.
        newView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Remove the row from its parent (the container view).
                // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
                // this removal is automatically animated.
                mContainerView.removeView(newView);

            }
        });

        newView.findViewById(R.id.time).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                timePickerGroupView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
        // adding this view is automatically animated.
        mContainerView.addView(newView, mContainerView.getChildCount());

    }

    public void timeSelected (View v) {
        hour = TimePickerView.getCurrentHour();
        minutes = TimePickerView.getCurrentMinute();
        int id = (int) mContainerView.getTag();

        timeTextView.setText(hour + ":" + minutes);
        timePickerGroupView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#191919"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="4"
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="00:00" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/meal"
        android:hint="Meal"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/PrimaryColor"/>
    <!-- A button that, when pressed, will delete this list item row from its container. -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ic_remove_circle_outline_white_48dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_remove_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/PrimaryColor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, how can I get @time updated properly.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: When creating the view can you use `view.setTag` to set the position info?

Comment: I have tried _italic_ **bols** `mContainerView.addView(newView, mContainerView.getChildCount());
        newView.setTag(mContainerView.getChildCount());`

then gettingit from timeSelected with v.getTag(). But the getTag is always null.